# Directive to directive communication throwing error in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I expose a controller to another directive.  In the end, I would like to have a communication between directives.  Having the slideshow directive $compile the objects.  While have responsive-page directives update the slideshow directive.  First I need communication between them.

Heres the error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'slideshow', required by directive 'responsivePage', can't be found!
```

### [Check out the live code on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myz2c/5/)

**html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" id="weekly">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
  <div class="weekly-viewport" responsive-page >
      <ul class="page-collection">
       <li class="page-layout" ng-repeat="page in pages">
            <ul class="page shop-local-page">
                <li class="imageurl"><img ng-src="{{page.imageurl}}" alt="" /></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="inner-weekly">
          <slideshow></slideshow>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Pages) {
   $scope.name = 'Superhero';
   $scope.pages = Pages;
});

myApp.directive('slideshow', function($window){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'template1.html',
      controller: function($scope, Pages) {
        $scope.adPageData = Pages;
        $scope.adpageLength = $scope.adPageData.length;
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      }
  };
})
.directive('responsivePage', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'slideshow',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, slideshowCtrl) {
       var targetRatio = 0.8419689;
       var pageCollectionWidth = angular.element(document.querySelector('.page-collection'))[0].offsetWidth;
       var pageCollectionHeight = angular.element(document.querySelector('.page-collection'))[0].offsetHeight;
       scope.properPageWidth = pageCollectionHeight*targetRatio;
       console.log();
    }
  }
});     
myApp.factory('Pages', function() {
   var Pages = {};
   Pages = [
     {
       'imageurl': 'http://placekitten.com/680/819',
       'imgWidth': 680,
       'imgHeight': 819
     },
     {
       'imageurl': 'http://placekitten.com/680/819',
       'imgWidth': 680,
       'imgHeight': 819
     },
     {
       'imageurl': 'http://placekitten.com/680/819',
       'imgWidth': 680,
       'imgHeight': 819
     }
   ]
   return Pages;
});
```

Comment: try `require: '^slideshow'` (notice the `^`) to look also for its ancestor.

Comment: It stopped throwing the error @MarcKline after putting the ^ inside.  Honestly I just want to have access to the $scope.adPageData.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I misread your code. I didn't see that `responsive-page` was contained in the template for `slideshow`.

Comment: @KhanhTO if you place a put the answer down I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `require: '^slideshow'` (notice the `^`) to look for `slideshow` controller on its ancestor.

From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> The ^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on
>   its parents (without the ^ prefix, the directive would look for the
>   controller on just its own element).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you.

Can be used directly.

```
myApp.directive('responsivePage', function(){
    return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, slideshowCtrl) {
        console.log(scope.adPageData);
        console.log(scope.adpageLength);

       var targetRatio = 0.8419689;
       var pageCollectionWidth = angular.element(document.querySelector('.page-collection'))[0].offsetWidth;
       var pageCollectionHeight = angular.element(document.querySelector('.page-collection'))[0].offsetHeight;
       scope.properPageWidth = pageCollectionHeight*targetRatio;
       console.log();
}
```

}
});

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myz2c/16/)

---

Another way of use

```
  myApp.directive('slideshow', function($window){
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          name:'aa_aa',//controller alias
          templateUrl: 'template1.html',
          controller: function($scope, Pages) {
              this.x ='x'
         },
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

         }
      };
 })
 .directive('responsivePage', function(){
     return{
         restrict: 'A',
         require: '^aa_aa',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, $controller) {
             console.log($controller)

         }
     }
  });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myz2c/47/)